# Ethereum Remix equivalent for EOS?

Tags: smart-contract, ethereum

Is there an equivalent online IDE for EOS to write the smart contracts?
https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

The closest I've seen to a web IDE for EOSIO is Todd Fleming's [cib project](https://tbfleming.github.io/cib/eos.html), but it doesn't seem like it's still [actively updated](https://github.com/tbfleming/cib) anymore, and I know if it was meant to be anything more than a fun experiment.